# How to ensure Typescript types recursive functions correctly?

Tags: typescript, recursion, inferred-type

I am facing a very tricky Typescript problem.

I am writing a small user-input validator library that validates bits of user-input that can be infinitely nested. A piece of user input can be one of either boolean, number, string (primitive) or array or object.

The test below shows how it works (and the link below takes you to a demo of the whole library - all working, except for this types problem).

```
it('validates an invalid array of objs of prims correctly', () => {
    const value = [
        { name: 'adam' },
        { name: 'jade' },
        { name: 's' },
    ];
    const descriptor: ValidatorArrayFieldDescriptor = {
        required: true,
        type: 'array',
        children: {
            type: 'object',
            children: {
                name: {
                    type: 'string',
                    rules: [
                        { type: 'min', params: { size: 2 } }
                    ],
                },
            },
        },
    };
    const result = validator.checkValue({
        value,
        descriptor,
    });
    expect(result.messages.length).toBe(0);
    expect(result.children[0].children.name.messages.length).toBe(0);
    expect(result.children[0].children.name.isValid).toBe(true);
    expect(result.children[1].children.name.messages.length).toBe(0);
    expect(result.children[1].children.name.isValid).toBe(true);
    expect(result.children[2].children.name.messages.length).toBe(1);
    expect(result.children[2].children.name.isValid).toBe(false);
    expect(result.isValid).toBe(false);
    expect(result.selfIsValid).toBe(true);
    expect(result.childrenAreValid).toBe(false);
});
```

**Full implementation is here**

https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-forest-2wcxjz?file=/src/validator.ts

**Minimal example also attached here**

```js
import { startCase } from "lodash";

// ############################################################################
// Utils
// ############################################################################

function formatPropKey(rawName: string): string {
  return utilFns.ucFirst(startCase(rawName).toLowerCase());
}

function isObject(obj: any) {
  if (typeof obj === "boolean") return false;
  if (typeof obj === "number") return false;
  if (typeof obj === "string") return false;
  if (typeof obj === "undefined") return false;
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) return false;
  let out = false;
  try {
    Object.keys(obj);
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function ucFirst(str: string): string {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

function ensureArray<T = any>(arr: any): T[] {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr as T[];
  if (!arr) return [] as T[];
  return [arr] as T[];
}

const utilFns = {
  isObject,
  ucFirst,
  ensureArray
};


// ############################################################################
// Types
// ############################################################################

export type ValidatorRuleType =
  | "min"
  | "max"
  | "pattern"

// ====

export interface ValidatorRuleMinParams {
  size: number;
}

// ====

export interface ValidatorRuleMaxParams {
  size: number;
}

// ====

export interface ValidatorRulePatternParams {
  pattern: RegExp;
}

// ===

export interface ValidatorTagValidityInfo {
  subMessage: string;
}

// ===

export interface ValidatorTagsValidityInfo {
  subMessage: string;
  plural: boolean;
}

// ===

export interface ValidatorBlackperiodsValidityInfo {
  subMessage: string;
  plural: boolean;
}

// ====

export type AnyValidatorRuleParams =
  | ValidatorRuleMinParams
  | ValidatorRuleMaxParams
  | ValidatorRulePatternParams
  | ValidatorRuleOneOfParams;
export type AnyValidityInfo =
  | ValidatorTagValidityInfo
  | ValidatorTagsValidityInfo
  | ValidatorBlackperiodsValidityInfo;

// ============================================================================

export interface BuiltInValidatorParams<
  T = AnyValidatorRuleParams | undefined
> {
  value: any;
  dataType: ValidatorFieldDataType;
  ruleParams: T;
}

export interface BuiltInValidatorMessageGetterParams<
  RuleParams = AnyValidatorRuleParams | undefined,
  ValidityInfo = AnyValidityInfo | undefined
> {
  propKey: string;
  dataType: ValidatorFieldDataType;
  ruleParams: RuleParams;
  validityInfo: ValidityInfo;
}

// ============================================================================

export type ValidatorFieldDataType =
  | "string"
  | "boolean"
  | "number"
  | "array"
  | "object";

// ============================================================================

export interface ValidatorFieldRule {
  type: ValidatorRuleType;
  params: any;
}

export interface ValidatorBooleanFieldDescriptor {
  type: "boolean";
  required?: boolean;
  rules?: ValidatorFieldRule[];
}

export interface ValidatorNumberFieldDescriptor {
  type: "number";
  required?: boolean;
  rules?: ValidatorFieldRule[];
}

export interface ValidatorStringFieldDescriptor {
  type: "string";
  required?: boolean;
  rules?: ValidatorFieldRule[];
}

export interface ValidatorArrayFieldDescriptor {
  type: "array";
  required?: boolean;
  rules?: ValidatorFieldRule[];
  children: AnyValidatorFieldDescriptor;
}

export interface ValidatorObjectFieldDescriptor {
  type: "object";
  required?: boolean;
  rules?: ValidatorFieldRule[];
  children: { [key: string]: AnyValidatorFieldDescriptor };
}

export type AnyValidatorFieldDescriptor =
  | ValidatorBooleanFieldDescriptor
  | ValidatorNumberFieldDescriptor
  | ValidatorStringFieldDescriptor
  | ValidatorArrayFieldDescriptor
  | ValidatorObjectFieldDescriptor;

export type PickValidatorFieldDescriptor<
  T extends ValidatorFieldDataType
> = T extends "boolean"
  ? ValidatorBooleanFieldDescriptor
  : T extends "number"
  ? ValidatorNumberFieldDescriptor
  : T extends "string"
  ? ValidatorStringFieldDescriptor
  : T extends "array"
  ? ValidatorArrayFieldDescriptor
  : T extends "object"
  ? ValidatorObjectFieldDescriptor
  : never;

// ============================================================================

export interface ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult {
  isValid: boolean;
  messages: string[];
}

export interface ValidatorFieldArrayResult {
  isValid: boolean;
  messages: string[];
  selfIsValid: boolean;
  childrenAreValid: boolean;
  children: ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult[];
}

export interface ValidatorFieldObjectResult {
  isValid: boolean;
  messages: string[];
  selfIsValid: boolean;
  childrenAreValid: boolean;
  children: {
    [key: string]: ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult;
  };
}

export type PickValidatorFieldResult<
  T extends ValidatorFieldDataType
> = T extends "boolean"
  ? ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult
  : T extends "number"
  ? ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult
  : T extends "string"
  ? ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult
  : T extends "array"
  ? ValidatorFieldArrayResult
  : T extends "object"
  ? ValidatorFieldObjectResult
  : never;

export type AnyValidatorFieldResult =
  | ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult
  | ValidatorFieldArrayResult
  | ValidatorFieldObjectResult;

// ############################################################################
// Built in system checks
// ############################################################################

export const builtInSystemChecks = {
  required: (propKey: string) => {
    return `${formatPropKey(propKey)} must be supplied.`;
  },
  incorrectFormat: (propKey: string, expected: string, got: string) => {
    return `${formatPropKey(
      propKey
    )} should be a ${expected}, but as a ${got}.`;
  }
};

// ############################################################################
// Built-in validators
// ############################################################################

export const builtInValidators: {
  [key: string]: {
    message: (params: any) => string;
    fn: (
      params: any
    ) => {
      valid: boolean;
      validityInfo?: any;
    };
  };
} = {
  min: {
    message: (
      params: BuiltInValidatorMessageGetterParams<ValidatorRuleMinParams>
    ) => {
      const { propKey, dataType, ruleParams } = params;
      const { size } = ruleParams;
      if (dataType === "string") {
        return `${formatPropKey(
          propKey
        )} must have no fewer than ${size} characters`;
      } else if (dataType === "number") {
        return `${formatPropKey(propKey)} must be no smaller than ${size}`;
      } else if (dataType === "array" || dataType === "object") {
        return `${formatPropKey(
          propKey
        )} must have no fewer than ${size} items`;
      } else {
        throw new Error(
          `The rule "min" cannot be used on a datatype of "${dataType}".`
        );
      }
    },
    fn: (params: BuiltInValidatorParams<ValidatorRuleMinParams>) => {
      const { value, dataType, ruleParams } = params;
      const { size } = ruleParams;
      const sizeValue = (() => {
        if (dataType === "string") {
          return value.length;
        } else if (dataType === "number") {
          return value;
        } else if (dataType === "array") {
          return value.length;
        } else if (dataType === "object") {
          return Object.keys(value).length;
        } else {
          throw new Error(
            `The rule "min" cannot be used on a datatype of "${dataType}".`
          );
        }
      })();
      const givenSize = Number.parseInt(sizeValue, 10) || 0;
      return { valid: givenSize >= size };
    }
  },
  max: {
    message: (
      params: BuiltInValidatorMessageGetterParams<ValidatorRuleMaxParams>
    ) => {
      const { propKey, dataType, ruleParams } = params;
      const { size } = ruleParams;
      if (dataType === "string") {
        return `${formatPropKey(
          propKey
        )} must have no fewer than ${size} characters`;
      } else if (dataType === "number") {
        return `${formatPropKey(propKey)} must be no smaller than ${size}`;
      } else if (dataType === "array" || dataType === "object") {
        return `${formatPropKey(
          propKey
        )} must have no fewer than ${size} items`;
      } else {
        throw new Error(
          `The rule "max" cannot be used on a datatype of "${dataType}".`
        );
      }
    },
    fn: (params: BuiltInValidatorParams<ValidatorRuleMinParams>) => {
      const { value, dataType, ruleParams } = params;
      const { size } = ruleParams;
      const sizeValue = (() => {
        if (dataType === "string") {
          return value.length;
        } else if (dataType === "number") {
          return value;
        } else if (dataType === "array") {
          return value.length;
        } else if (dataType === "object") {
          return Object.keys(value).length;
        } else {
          throw new Error(
            `The rule "max" cannot be used on a datatype of "${dataType}".`
          );
        }
      })();
      const givenSize = Number.parseInt(sizeValue, 10) || 0;
      return { valid: givenSize <= size };
    }
  },
  pattern: {
    message: (
      params: BuiltInValidatorMessageGetterParams<ValidatorRulePatternParams>
    ) => {
      const { propKey, dataType, ruleParams } = params;
      const { pattern } = ruleParams;
      return `${formatPropKey(
        propKey
      )} must match the pattern "${pattern.toString()}"`;
    },
    fn: (params: BuiltInValidatorParams<ValidatorRulePatternParams>) => {
      const { value, dataType, ruleParams } = params;
      const { pattern } = ruleParams;
      return { valid: pattern.test(value || "") };
    }
  },
};

// ############################################################################
// Check value
// ############################################################################

interface CheckSingleValueProps<T extends ValidatorFieldDataType> {
  value: any;
  descriptor: PickValidatorFieldDescriptor<T>;
  propKey?: string;
  validationEnabled?: boolean;
  auxData?: any;
}

function checkValue<T extends ValidatorFieldDataType>({
  value,
  descriptor,
  propKey = "thisValue",
  validationEnabled,
  auxData
}: CheckSingleValueProps<T>): PickValidatorFieldResult<T> {
  const isBoolean = typeof value === "boolean";
  const hasBoolean =
    descriptor.type === "boolean" && (value === false || value === true);

  const isString = typeof value === "string";
  const hasString =
    descriptor.type === "string" &&
    typeof value === "string" &&
    value.length > 0;

  const isNumber = typeof value === "number";
  const hasNumber = descriptor.type === "number" && typeof value === "number";

  const isArray = Array.isArray(value);
  const hasArray = descriptor.type === "array" && Array.isArray(value);

  const isObject = utilFns.isObject(value);
  const hasObject = descriptor.type === "object" && utilFns.isObject(value);

  const isPrimitive = isBoolean || isString || isNumber;
  const hasValue =
    hasBoolean || hasString || hasNumber || hasArray || hasObject;

  if (descriptor.type === "boolean") {
    if (descriptor.required && !hasBoolean) {
      const out: ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult = {
        messages: [builtInSystemChecks.required(propKey)],
        isValid: false
      };
      return out as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    }
    if (!isBoolean) {
      const out: ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult = {
        messages: [
          builtInSystemChecks.incorrectFormat(propKey, "boolean", typeof value)
        ],
        isValid: false
      };
      return out as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    }
  }

  if (descriptor.type === "string") {
    if (descriptor.required && !hasString) {
      const out: ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult = {
        messages: [builtInSystemChecks.required(propKey)],
        isValid: false
      };
      return out as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    }
    if (!isString) {
      const out: ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult = {
        messages: [
          builtInSystemChecks.incorrectFormat(propKey, "string", typeof value)
        ],
        isValid: false
      };
      return out as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    }
  }

  if (descriptor.type === "number") {
    if (descriptor.required && !hasNumber) {
      const out: ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult = {
        messages: [builtInSystemChecks.required(propKey)],
        isValid: false
      };
      return out as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    }
    if (!isNumber) {
      const out: ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult = {
        messages: [
          builtInSystemChecks.incorrectFormat(propKey, "number", typeof value)
        ],
        isValid: false
      };
      return out as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    }
  }

  if (descriptor.type === "array") {
    if (descriptor.required && !hasArray) {
      const out: ValidatorFieldArrayResult = {
        messages: [builtInSystemChecks.required(propKey)],
        isValid: false,
        selfIsValid: false,
        childrenAreValid: true,
        children: []
      };
      return out as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    }
    if (!isArray) {
      const out: ValidatorFieldArrayResult = {
        messages: [
          builtInSystemChecks.incorrectFormat(propKey, "array", typeof value)
        ],
        isValid: false,
        selfIsValid: false,
        childrenAreValid: true,
        children: []
      };
      return out as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    }
  }

  if (descriptor.type === "object") {
    if (descriptor.required && !hasObject) {
      const out: ValidatorFieldObjectResult = {
        messages: [builtInSystemChecks.required(propKey)],
        isValid: false,
        selfIsValid: false,
        childrenAreValid: true,
        children: {}
      };
      return out as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    }
    if (!isObject) {
      const out: ValidatorFieldObjectResult = {
        messages: [
          builtInSystemChecks.incorrectFormat(propKey, "object", typeof value)
        ],
        isValid: false,
        selfIsValid: false,
        childrenAreValid: true,
        children: {}
      };
      return out as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    }
  }

  function mapRules(rules: any, output: any) {
    utilFns.ensureArray(rules).forEach((rule) => {
      const result = builtInValidators[rule.type].fn({
        value,
        dataType: descriptor.type,
        ruleParams: rule.params
      });
      if (!result.valid) {
        const message = builtInValidators[rule.type].message({
          propKey,
          dataType: descriptor.type,
          ruleParams: rule.params,
          validityInfo: result.validityInfo
        });
        output.messages.push(message);
        output.isValid = false;
      }
    });
  }

  if (
    descriptor.type === "boolean" ||
    descriptor.type === "number" ||
    descriptor.type === "string"
  ) {
    const output: ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult = {
      messages: [],
      isValid: true
    };
    if (hasValue) {
      mapRules(descriptor.rules, output);
    }
    return output as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
  } else if (descriptor.type === "array") {
    const output: ValidatorFieldArrayResult = {
      isValid: true,
      selfIsValid: true,
      childrenAreValid: true,
      messages: [],
      children: []
    };
    if (hasValue) {
      mapRules(descriptor.rules, output);
      if (!output.isValid) output.selfIsValid = false;
      output.children = value.map((childValue: any) => {
        const result = checkValue({
          value: childValue,
          descriptor: descriptor.children
        });
        if (!result.isValid) {
          output.childrenAreValid = false;
          output.isValid = false;
        }
        return result;
      });
    }
    return output as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
  } else if (descriptor.type === "object") {
    const output: ValidatorFieldObjectResult = {
      isValid: true,
      selfIsValid: true,
      childrenAreValid: true,
      messages: [],
      children: {}
    };
    if (hasValue) {
      mapRules(descriptor.rules, output);
      if (!output.isValid) output.selfIsValid = false;
      output.children = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(descriptor.children).map((ruleEntry) => {
          const [childKey, childDescriptor] = ruleEntry as [
            string,
            AnyValidatorFieldDescriptor
          ];
          const childValue = value[childKey];
          const result = checkValue({
            value: childValue,
            descriptor: childDescriptor,
            propKey: childKey
          });
          if (!result.isValid) {
            output.childrenAreValid = false;
            output.isValid = false;
          }
          return [childKey, result];
        })
      );
    }
    return output as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
  } else {
    throw new Error("Value was not primitive, array, or object.");
  }

  throw new Error(`Invalid descriptor type: "${descriptor.type}"`);
}

// ############################################################################
// Validate one record
// ############################################################################

// function checkRecord<Rec, Rules>({
//  record,
//  rules,
//  auxData,
//  validationEnabled = true,
// }: UseValidatedRecordProps): UseValidatedRecordData {

// }

// ############################################################################
// Validate many records
// ############################################################################

// function checkRecords<Rec, Rules>({
//  records,
//  rules,
//  auxData,
//  validationEnabled,
// }: UseValidatedRecordsProps): UseValidatedRecordsData {

// }

// ############################################################################
// Output
// ############################################################################

export const validator = {
  bivs: builtInValidators,
  biscs: builtInSystemChecks,
  checkValue,
  utils: {}
};
```

As I say, the implemenation functions fine. The problem is that the mechanism I've written (that uses discriminated unions) is not functioning. Therefore, lines such as this raise TS errors:

Line:

`expect(result.children[1].children.name.isValid).toBe(true)`

Error:

`Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult | ValidatorFieldArrayResult | ValidatorFieldObjectResult'.`

This is because TS thinks that the validation result is always one of 3 result types, when I expect TS to narrow it down based on my use of literal members and `if` statements.

The whole code is too long to post here (but please see link for the full code) but I will post the section I describe to keep this post complete:

```
    if (descriptor.type === 'boolean' || descriptor.type === 'number' || descriptor.type === 'string') {
        const output: ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult = {
            messages: [],
            isValid: true,
        };
        if (hasValue) {
            mapRules(descriptor.rules, output);
        }
        return output as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    } else if (descriptor.type === 'array') {
        const output: ValidatorFieldArrayResult = {
            isValid: true,
            selfIsValid: true,
            childrenAreValid: true,
            messages: [],
            children: [],
        };
        if (hasValue) {
            mapRules(descriptor.rules, output);
            if (!output.isValid) output.selfIsValid = false;
            output.children = value.map((childValue: any) => {
                const result = checkValue({
                    value: childValue,
                    descriptor: descriptor.children,
                });
                if (!result.isValid) {
                    output.childrenAreValid = false;
                    output.isValid = false;
                }
                return result;
            });
        }
        return output as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    } else if (descriptor.type === 'object') {
        const output: ValidatorFieldObjectResult = {
            isValid: true,
            selfIsValid: true,
            childrenAreValid: true,
            messages: [],
            children: {},
        }
        if (hasValue) {
            mapRules(descriptor.rules, output);
            if (!output.isValid) output.selfIsValid = false;
            output.children = Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(descriptor.children).map(ruleEntry => {
                    const [childKey, childDescriptor] = ruleEntry as [string, AnyValidatorFieldDescriptor];
                    const childValue = value[childKey];
                    const result = checkValue({
                        value: childValue,
                        descriptor: childDescriptor,
                        propKey: childKey,
                    });
                    if (!result.isValid) {
                        output.childrenAreValid = false;
                        output.isValid = false;
                    }
                    return [childKey, result];
                })
            );
        }
        return output as PickValidatorFieldResult<T>;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Value was not primitive, array, or object.');
    }
```

What I really want to avoid is having to do something like this (which will be repeated in many places where I am using the validator)

`(((result as ValidatorFieldArrayResult).children[0] as ValidatorFieldObjectResult).children.name as ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult).messages.length`

Unfortunately I can't pass the types in a call-time due to the possibly infinite recursion and many-pronged branching of the validation walk.

Only other thing I can think of doing is using `any`, but surely there is a better way!

Comment: "The whole code is too long to post here (but please see link for the full code) but I will post the section I describe to keep this post complete" Please do try to produce a [mre].  It should be neither the whole code, nor a fragment that requires navigating away from Stack Overflow to put in context.  You might want to build one from scratch that has a similar issue.

Comment: ① Does this question depend on lodash? If so you might want to tag it as such so that relevant experts get eyes on it. If not, you might want to remove references to it from your code so that nobody needs to install it or chase down its typings in order to proceed. ② Your self-contained example is very long (hundreds of lines), and while it's technically possible that this is truly the smallest example demonstrating the issue, my experience with TypeScript questions on Stack Overflow suggests it's *very unlikely*.  Please try to minimize; again, you might want to start from scratch.

Comment: I've trimmed it down a bit - hope this is ok. Its difficult to cut it down further without removing the essential interfaces or main function that processes the data that pertains to the typing conundrum.

Comment: Oh well, it's too long for me to be able to look at it easily.  Maybe someone else will come along who can pore over it.  Or maybe I can look at it in depth later.  If nobody else engages helpfully, I do suggest you build up from scratch rather than trying to trim stuff down, if possible.  Presumably you're just dealing with the problem that you can't infer `T` from `CheckSingleValueProps<T>` because the latter type is a conditional type.  This can probably be rectified via refactoring the types, but I'm not currently in the position to deal with such a large example.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Yep, TS is not inferring types for some reason. As far as I can see, CheckSingleValueProps<T> isn't conditional in the strictest sense, but it is generic. Not sure why this would stop TS from inferring types correctly.

Comment: Since `CheckSingleValueProps<T>` can only possibly infer `T` from `PickValidatorFieldDescriptor<T>`, which is conditional in the strict sense, the whole thing falls into the category of "generic conditional type" (technically "a type that depends on a conditional type that depends on a generic type parameter") and you can't really get reasonable inference from it.  The compiler doesn't have human level intelligence so it can't do abstract analysis to reverse every type function; the question "given `F<T>=U`, what is `T`" is only answerable by the compiler for specific forms of `F`.

Comment: I can't tell if it's the validator that's the problem, the combo, or the nesting. If it's the validator itself, could you just make an example with a string validator? If two validators are required, int and string. Or if nesting, just a string and object?  Also maybe jcalz knows the answer.

Comment: I mean, if there was just a string validator, then there would only be one return type, which is ValidatorFieldPrimativeResult, and then I wouldn't have the problem with TS not being able to narrow down to a single return type out of 3 return types. I can try to create a simplified example, but I fear I will create something impertinent to the real issue.

Comment: I've stripped the example down to the function in question, (which I've highlighted as the important part), and apart from that there are only the associated interfaces, and 3 validation constraint functions for illustrative purposes. Not really sure how else I can reliably cut it down without already knowing the answer to my own question.

Comment: I've written something that I think might be close. Will post in another question.